# How to cut PCB?

Tags: pcb, materials

This is actually an answer to a thread that was recently "protected" before this answer could be posted. I've tried various saw blades on FR-4 but it dulls them too quickly. A hacksaw works but I found a better way: a carbide tipped tile scoring hand tool. See photo. I etched my board first so I was cutting sections apart along separation lines, so I'm not sure how well it does cutting through the copper itself. I believe it will do quite well. Procedure: hold a ruler along the path to cut, score lightly with the tool, move the ruler, and follow the score repeatedly to deepen it. You can go deep enough on one side to break the board, but I recommend scoring both sides. (You can score all the way through, of course.) Use a diamond-dust hone (coarse grade) to polish the broken edge. The kerf is about 2mm+ if done one-sided, less if scoring both sides. Really rips through and doesn't get dull.
[image: http://www.stmradio.com/DSCF6067.JPG]

Comment: Sadly, this literally isn't a question.

Comment: If you get just even a little rep, then you can post this as an answer to the question. Probably this will be deleted, since it really isn't a question at all.

Comment: I think it only takes 10 rep to add answers to protected questions, and you now have 55.  You should now be able to copy and paste this as a answer where it belongs.  We really can't leave this open as a question.

Comment: Would if I could but my name has a 4 beside it and I can't find any button to add my answer to the original thread.

Comment: I upvoted because it sounds like a good advise and you can make your edit on the original question.